# TogglerBar with Show

Tags: plotting

Writing:

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot[{x, x}, {x, 0, 1}];
plot2 = ParametricPlot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 1}];
plot3 = ParametricPlot[{x, x^3}, {x, 0, 1}];

DynamicModule[{
  select = {1, 2, 3}},
 Column[{
   TogglerBar[Dynamic[select],
    {1 -> "p1", 2 -> "p2", 3 -> "p3"}],
   Dynamic@Show[
     {plot1, plot2, plot3}[[select]],
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
   }]
 ]
```

I get:

[image]

but if I deselect all three boxes I get an error.

1. How can I avoid this error by simply plotting nothing?
2. How can I plot everything in the middle of the page, including the boxes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To align things in the center of the notebook, you can use [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane). To center the toggler bar and the graphic, you can use the [`Alignment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alignment) option of [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column). Finally, one idea to avoid the error when no graphic is selected is to use an empty [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object as the first argument of [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show) instead. Here is an example doing this:

```
DynamicModule[{select={1,2,3}},
    Pane[
        Column[
            {
            TogglerBar[Dynamic[select],{1->"p1",2->"p2",3->"p3"}],
            Dynamic@Show[
                (* control graphics option by giving them in an empty graphic *)
                Graphics[{}, Axes->True,PlotRange->{{0,1},{1,0}}],
                {plot1,plot2,plot3}[[select]]]
            },
            Alignment->Center (* center toggler bar and graphic *)
        ],
        ImageSize->Full, Alignment->Center (* center within notebook *)
    ]
]
```

[image]

And here is the output after deselecting all plots:

[image]

Comment: @TeM That should probably be a separate question. You can modify the size using something like `BaseStyle -> {SetterBoxOptions -> {FrameMargins -> {{20, 20}, {0, 0}}}}`. I don't know how to change the color.

Answer (score 3):

```
colors = ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 5]];
plots = Table[ParametricPlot[{x, x^i}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> colors[[i]]], {i, 3}];

DynamicModule[{select = {1, 2, 3}}, Dynamic@Show[{plots[[select]], Graphics[{}]}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotLabel -> TogglerBar[Dynamic[select], 
     Table[i -> Grid[{{Item[Pane[Style[x^i, 16, Bold, "Panel", Opacity[1], colors[[i]],
      Background -> Opacity[0]], ImageSize -> {60, 20}, Alignment -> Center], 
   Background -> Opacity[If[MemberQ[select, i], .5, .2], colors[[i]]], 
   FrameStyle -> If[MemberQ[select, i], Darker@colors[[i]],  Opacity[0]]]}}], {i, 1, 3}],
   Appearance -> "Frameless"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @TeM, use replace `select = {1, 2, 3}`  with `select = {}`.