# How can I toggle display of individual items in a Show list?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, display

I have several ListLinePlot features I'm overlaying on one image using Show. I'm using the Manipulate function to turn on one at a time, but I'd like to be able to use Manipulate to toggle the individual Show images on/off. Is there any way to create a Manipulate function that would allow this?

```
plotA = ListLinePlot[{{{-2000, 500}, {-10, 0}, {10, 0}, {2000, 1800}}}, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> {{-2000, 2000}, {-400, 4000}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];

plotB = ListLinePlot[{{-800, 4000}, {-300, 200}, {0, 3000}, {300, 200}, {800, 4000}}, PlotRange -> {{-2000, 2000}, {-400, 4000}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Blue];

plotC = ListLinePlot[{{-1000, 3000}, {-600, 400}, {0, 1600}, {600, 400}, {1000, 3000}}, PlotRange -> {{-2000, 2000}, {-400, 4000}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Orange];

Show[plotA, plotB, plotC]
```

Is there any way to have a Manipulate object that could toggle each of these on/off individually so one, two, all, or none would be displayed by the Show function?

This is the code I've been able to work with, but again, I can only show one plot at a time this way.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[a], {{a, plotA, ""}, {plotA -> "plot a", plotB -> "plot b", 
   plotC -> "plot c"}}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate:[TogglerBar with Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166354/125)

Comment: @kglr The functionality in that solution will work for me. Thank you very much.